# Objective-C: How to convert following JSON to usable data

Tags: objective-c, json

I have a JSON string like the following

```
    [["Exampe_Level0_1","Exampe_Level1_1","Exampe_Level2_1","Exampe_Level3_1","Exampe_Level4_1","Exampe_Level5_1"],["Exampe_Level0_2","Exampe_Level1_2","Exampe_Level2_2","Exampe_Level3_2","Exampe_Level4_2","Exampe_Level5_2"]]
```

I also have a class

ExampleClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ExampleClass : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *Level0;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *Level1;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *Level2;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *Level3;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *Level4;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *Level5;
@end
```

Obviously in the JSON string, the first item in array is ExampleClass Level0, second item in array is ExampleClass Level1 etc.

Ideally i want to convert the JSON data into a format into either a NSMutableArray to NSDictionary. Im just lost as to how to convert it.

Thanks

Comment: NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: @user3521174 Where did you get the JSON in the question?

Answer (score 0):

First you convert your string to NSData. Assume the NSString JSONString contains your JSON string:

```
NSData* JSONData = [JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then convert this data into an NSArray:

```
NSError *e;
NSArray* finalData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONData options:nil error:&e];
```

The Object `finalData` will contain all your elements. Note however that looking at your string it seems as if finalData itself will contain 2 arrays. Those 2 arrays will have your strings

Comment: Note that the example JSON is not a `NSString`, note that the quote characters are not escaped.